# How to create a parent layout in VueJS

Tags: templates, vue.js, layout, architecture

I have the following component structure and code of components: [structure and code](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/103uakJjTKLrjT7pUEYFpC1EmFE3l9FoHVdBhykieTQs/edit)

There are two layouts: UserLayout and OrganizationLayout.

OrganizationLayout looks like UserLayout, but the difference is only navigation component inside a header.

Also both OrganizationLayout and UserLayout requires user profile data to be rendered. Therefore I want to inherit OrganizationLayout from UserLayout and loads data only in a one place - inside UserLayout component.

I have tried to use Vue.js slots feature to do it, but after rendering component tree looks like:

```
OrganizationLayout
  UserLayout
    HeaderTemplate
```

but I expect:

```
UserLayout
  OrganizationLayout
     HeaderTeamplate
```

How can I do it?

**UPDATE:**
I have found the same problem discussed here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6811

Comment: Can you please add your code. It is difficult to point you towards your mistake without seeing what you actually did.

Comment: MarcRo, if you opened a structure link, you could see a code.

Comment: The pseudo code snippet you provided does not show how you are implementing the structure of inheritance. One component should be nested inside the other? Or are they extending one another and you only change the template?

Comment: "The pseudo code snippet you provided does not show how you are implementing the structure of inheritance" - because this is a question how to do it. OrganizationLayout component should be inherited from UserLayout.

Comment: MarcRo, looks like you misunderstand a problem and didn't look at github issue before comment.

Comment: This issue is exactly describing inheritance between components (in template scope). There is a way to implement the exact feature the post asks for with an additional webpackLoader someone else was kind enough to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue cannot be solved with a Vue.js without plugins or html preprocessors for a while. To get more information, please see: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6811

You can use Pug or plugin (look at issue above) to extend component's templates.
To extend logic only, you can use Vue "extend".